# what to do after Rstudio stop ?working after latest update?

Tags: r, rstudio

I did the last update this morning, and thereafter also of R.

I also download [this from windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows-c0514201-7fe6-95a3-b0a5-287930f3560c) as I am using W8.1

Re-installed and re-booted several times.

links for [window](https://gyazo.com/da6e8189260c4f4c87089a462b83c24e)s and [rstudio error.](https://gyazo.com/63cc2ed056637d007133f49a8bb4dda1)

What should I do? thank you

Comment: The RStudio website says the latest version only supports Windows 10/11. You'll probably need to use an older version https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-for-windows-8-1/72313/2

Comment: Thanks. Same for R too ?